# How to design query evaluation in C# like Tfs?

Tags: c#, expression, conditional-statements

I am working on an Asp.net web application, and I have a requirement to design query evaluations as Tfs:

[image: Tfs queries]

I have come up with this table schema:

[image: ConditionGroups table]

Now I am planning to evaluate those expressions to get a value of true/false by evaluating each expression and combine its value with the value of the next expression depending on the Order column.

Could you please tell me if there is a better way to implement that using C#?

And For My approach how to build dynamic expressions using C# Expression library?

Comment: As an advise: Be careful when you want to combine `AND` and `OR` operators. You have to build some kind of bracket system. When you have a condition like "r AND s OR t OR u AND v" it is not clear which conditions should be linked together via `AND` or `OR`. The `order` field cannot solve this problem.

Comment: @Progman But I think if I evaluated each condition then I evaluated it with the next condition that case will not be an issue
true || false = true
Then the value I get from the first two condtions with the third condition
true && false=false

Comment: You can use C# `Expression`s to build dynamic conditions like this. As a bonus, such conditions will work also for database queries, given that you are using something like Entity Framework. If that question were not put on hold - I could have provided an example.

Comment: I have found a real good resource to implement it using Expression library [Build-Lambda-Expressions-Dynamically](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079028/Build-Lambda-Expressions-Dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
Do you need to be able to do filtering for arbitrary classes or just for one fooClass? In the latter case, you can let every filterable class implement a simple interface, and access that for filtering. As an example, you can do something like this

```
public interface IFilterableByFlags<T>
{
  Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool, bool>> GetFilters();
  IEnumerable<T> ApplyFilters(IEnumerable<T> collection, Dictionary<string, bool> filterValues);
}

public class FooFilters : IFilterableByFlags<fooClass>
{
  public Dictionary<string, Func<fooClasss, bool, bool>> GetFilters()
  {
    var filters = new Dictionary<string, Func<fooClass, bool, bool>>();
    filters["AdminAccess"] = (obj, val) => obj.AdminAccess == val;
    filters["ChildRestrictions"] = (obj, val) => obj.ChildRestrictions == val;
    return filters;
  }

  public IEnumerable<fooClass> ApplyFilters(IEnumerable<fooClass> collection, Dictionary<string, bool> filterValues)
  {
    var filters = GetFilters();

    // this could be written using Linq Aggregate, but I prefer an
    // explicit loop. Simpler error handling (omitted here for brevity)
    foreach(var f in filtervalues)
    {
      collection = collection.Where(foo => filters[f.Key](foo, f.Value));
    }

    return collection;
  }
}
```

In this example I'm implementing filters in an external class, but one could easily extend the fooClass to incorporate the filters, mixing and matching this code to suit your needs and this code can be easily extended to support non-boolean filters.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to store a group of queries , after that I will check specific entities from database to see which records have met the specified queries

Comment: So I need dynamic queries to be added , so later I can check which entities have met specific queries which  have been added by specific users

Comment: @SimpleCode great, So these filters if I may, are these boolean?

Comment: Yes they are boolean and if the final value is true I will display to the end user the records has met that group of conditions

Comment: @SimpleCode I've written down a way you can achieve this using `Func<>`